# Connection to SQL Server fails after Windows 10 update

Tags: python, r, sql-server, windows

I have a database on SQL Server which I had been connecting to in R without any trouble with the following connection string

```
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=XYZSERVERNAMEXYZ;database=mydatabase;trusted_connection=Yes')
```

Windows 10 just forced an update on me, and after re-booting, the connection fails with the message

> [RODBC] ERROR: state HYT00, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Login timeout expired

SQL Server Management Studio works fine and connecting through the command prompt works as expected as well. I tried using python and pyodbc with a similar result.

Comment: Do you mean `python`'s and `pyodbc`'s results are similar to the *not-working* or the *working* examples?

Comment: pyodbc returns `pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53)')`

Comment: Depending on what is installed, check Windows Firewall (`Win` button then `firewall`), and on the left you may see *"Allow an app or feature through Windows Defender Firewall"*. I'm not a windows-guru-admin, but that might be causing issue. If you have a different (in addition or instead), similar procedures apply.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that in upgrading to the latest build of Windows (build 18362.267), TCP/IP got disabled by the updater. Going to SQL Server configuration manager and enabling TCP/IP fixes the problem.

Odd that the Windows updates have this kind of behaviour.